# getting from list without duplicates (Groovy)

Tags: groovy

I have the following list and code

```
def myList = [[id:8100-04, name:AAA, code:2281], 
             [id:8100-05, name:BBB, code:2102], 
             [id:8100-06, name:CCC, code:6089], 
             [id:8100-07, name:CCC, code:6089], 
             [id:8100-08, name:CCC, code:6089]]
//list is retrived but looks something like the above

def newList = myList.findAll { 
            (it.get("Name").equals("AAA") || 
                it.get("Name").equals("BBB") || 
                it.get("Name").equals("AFBO") ||
                it.get("Name").equals("CCC")) }
def filteredListData = newList.collect { getListData(it.get("Id"), it.get("Name"), 
                                          it.get("Code")) }
```

I want to retrieve all of my newList and if there is a duplicate then retrieve the entry with the lowest id Index.

so from myList i am looking for the result to be:

```
[[id:8100-04, name:AAA, code:2281], 
[id:8100-05, name:BBB, code:2102], 
[id:8100-06, name:CCC, code:6089]]
```

Comment: JCK, Hope duplicate should be identified based on `name and code`. please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

```
def myList = [
                 [id:"8100-04", name:"AAA", code:2281], 
                 [id:"8100-05", name:"BBB", code:2102], 
                 [id:"8100-06", name:"CCC", code:6089], 
                 [id:"8100-07", name:"CCC", code:6089], 
                 [id:"8100-08", name:"CCC", code:6089]
             ]

def newList = myList.findAll { 
                it.name in ["AAA", "BBB", "AFBO", "CCC"]
               }

def map = [:]

newList.each{
    if(!map.get(it.name))
        map.put(it.name, it)

}               

println map*.value
```

**Output:**

```
[
 [id:8100-04, name:AAA, code:2281],
 [id:8100-05, name:BBB, code:2102],
 [id:8100-06, name:CCC, code:6089]
]
```

Comment: That works if the original list is sorted on id. Otherwise you have to do a sort first, or see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more "functional style" solution. We group by name, this gives a list for each name. Then we sort each of these lists and take its first element.

```
def myList = [[id:'8100-04', name:'AAA', code:2281], 
             [id:'8100-05', name:'BBB', code:2102], 
             [id:'8100-07', name:'CCC', code:6089], 
             [id:'8100-06', name:'CCC', code:6089], 
             [id:'8100-08', name:'CCC', code:6089]]

def newList = myList.findAll { 
                it.name in ["AAA", "BBB", "AFBO", "CCC"]
               }

def groups = newList.groupBy {it -> it.name}

def lowestIds = groups.collect({it.value.sort{it.id}[0]})

println lowestIds
```

Even simpler:

```
newList.sort{it.id}.unique{it.name}

println newList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script which addresses:

- Unsorted items, note that order is changed in `myList` below.
- OP did not mention the criteria for duplicate. This considers duplicate based on `name and code`

```groovy
def myList = [[id:'8100-07', name:'CCC', code:6089],
              [id:'8100-04', name:'AAA', code:2281],
              [id:'8100-05', name:'BBB', code:2102],
              [id:'8100-06', name:'CCC', code:6089], 
              [id:'8100-08', name:'CCC', code:6089]]


def newList = myList.findAll {
                it.get("name").equals("AAA") ||
                it.get("name").equals("BBB") ||
                it.get("name").equals("AFBO") ||
                it.get("name").equals("CCC")
} 
//Sort by order id, name and code fields
def criteria = { a,b -> a.id <=> b.id ?: a.name <=> b.name ?: a.code?: b.code }
//Group by name and code ; apply sort; get the first item; apply sort on final result
def result = newList.groupBy({it.name}, {it.code}).inject([]){li, k, v-> v.collect {key, value -> li << value.sort(criteria)[0]}; li}.sort(criteria)
println result
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5183170693562368)</kbd>